# How to switch image based on anchor tag using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, anchor

I have a lists of thumbnail images. When user clicks a small thumbnail image, it swaps it to show the full image.
I have been trying to get the anchor tag name so that I can explode the value `i`. But I can't get it working, any ideas?

My javascript:

```
function swap(image) {
   document.getElementById("main").src = image.href;
}
```

My HTML & PHP script:

```
<img id="main" src="images/main.jpg" width="226" height="226" alt="" />

<p><strong>Day <?php echo $i; ?>:</strong></strong><br /><?php echo $today[$i]; ?></p>
</div>
</div>

<?php
 for($i=1; $i<$day; $i++)
   {
     echo'<a href="images/prevDay-'.$i.'.jpg" name="day-'.$i.'" onclick="swap(this); return false;">';
     echo'<img src="images/thumbDay-'.$i.'.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="" title="thumbDay-'.$i.'.jpg" /></a> ';
   }
?>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't actually have any jQuery. You are using document.getElementById("main"), instead of $("#main")

Comment: i think i might have to declare another event so that the first event swap the image, and the second event will get me the anchor tag name. i did included another event like this. 
(a href="images/prevFeb-1.jpg?prevDay=1" onclick="swap(this); getAnchorName(); return false;")

unfortunately, when i click to swap my image, it went to a different page, rather than the swap window. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better giving it an ID instead or as well.

Accessing in jQuery then would be (for example):

```
$("#day-1")
```

Or without jQuery, just using your document.getElementById.

If you really want to get it by name:

```
$("a[name='day-1']")
```

Comment: i think i might have to declare another event so that the first event swap the image, and the second event will get me the anchor tag name. i did included another event like this. (a href="images/prevFeb-1.jpg?prevDay=1" onclick="swap(this); getAnchorName(); return false;") unfortunately, when i click to swap my image, it went to a different page, rather than the swap window. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you attribute class "thumbnail" for thumbnails, you may do

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function(){
   // $(this) refers to the clicked element
   $("#main").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"))

})
```

Note the use of `attr()` method as `getter` and `setter`

```
// getter:
$(selector).attr(attr_name) 

// setter
$(selector).attr(attr_name, attr_value)
```

Your PHP can be re-written as:

```
// no need for <a> element
<?php
 for($i=1; $i<$day; $i++)
   {
     echo'<img class="thumbnail" src="images/thumbDay-'.$i.'.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="" title="thumbDay-'.$i.'.jpg" />';
   }
?>
```